# Faster method to extract distinct string from an Arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java-8, distinct-values

I have an ArrayList of Dico and I try to extract a distinct string from Arraylist of Dico.

This is the Dico class.

```
public class Dico implements Comparable {
private final String m_term;
private double m_weight;
private final int m_Id_doc;

public Dico(int Id_Doc, String Term, double tf_ief) {
    this.m_Id_doc = Id_Doc;
    this.m_term = Term;
    this.m_weight = tf_ief;
}

public String getTerm() {
    return this.m_term;
}

public double getWeight() {
    return this.m_weight;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.m_weight = weight;
}

public int getDocId() {
    return this.m_Id_doc;
}
}
```

I use this function to extract 1000 distinct value from middle of this array:
i start form the middle and i take only distinct value in both direction left and right

> ```
> public static List <String> get_sinificativ_term(List<Dico> dico)
>  {
>    List <String> term =  new ArrayList();
>    int  pos_median= ( dico.size() / 2 );
>    int count=0;
>    int i=0;
>    int j=0;   
>   String temp_d = dico.get(pos_median).getTerm();
>   String temp_g =temp_d;
>   term.add(temp_d);
>
>  while(count < 999) // count of element 
>   {   
>    if(!temp_d.equals(dico.get( ( pos_median + i) ).getTerm()))
>
>  {    
>      temp_d = dico.get(( pos_median + i)).getTerm(); // save current term in temp
>      //  System.out.println(temp_d);
>        term.add(temp_d);  // add term to list                            
>        i++;     // go to the next value-->right
>        count++;
>      //  System.out.println(temp_d);
>    }
>
>   else
>        i++; // go to the next value-->right
>
>   if(!temp_g.equals(dico.get( ( pos_median+j ) ).getTerm()))
>
>  {    
>        temp_g = dico.get(( pos_median+j )).getTerm();
>
>       term.add(temp_g );// add term to array
>      //  System.out.println(temp_g);
>       j--; //  go to the next value-->left
>
>       count++;
>    }
>   else 
>          j--;//  go to the next value-->left
>
> }      
>     return term;
>  }
> ```

I would like to make my solution more faster than this function,if is possible can i make this with Java SE 8 Streams ?

Comment: Side note on code quality: consider using different variable names for i and j. Such single character names are ok for for-loop counters; but I think in your example, they have a much different usage. Better give them a name that represents what they actually are, like indexLeftOfMedian for i for example ...

Comment: What is the purpose for getting only 1000, and why do you start in the center?  Also, I assume you're expecting there to be duplicates of getTerm() in different array elements?

Comment: Your code will extract either 999 or 1000 elements. Your code breaks if there aren't at least 999 distinct values. It also doesn't work if the list is not sorted. You didn't state that it is. You know how large `term` should get so you can make it big enough in the first place. How much faster should it get? You always have to iterate, compare and collect. You can avoid repeated calls like `dico.get(( pos_median + i) ).getTerm()` and make your life easier by using a `.listIterator(pos_median)`.

Comment: @  zeroflagL ok,thank you for this information.

Answer (score 1):

Streams will not make it faster but can make it much simpler and clearer.

Here's the simplest version.  It will take all list indexes, sort them by distance to the middle of the list, get the corresponding term, filter out duplicates and limit to 1000 elements.  It will certainly be slower than your iterative code, but much easier to follow because the code neatly mirrors its English description:

```
public static List<String> get_sinificativ_term(List<Dico> dicolist) {
    int size = dicolist.size();

    return IntStream.range(0, size)
            .boxed()
            .sorted(comparing(i -> Math.abs(size / 2 - i)))
            .map(dicolist::get)
            .map(Dico::getTerm)
            .distinct()
            .limit(1000)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

If your list is really huge and you want to avoid sorting it, you can trade away some simplicity for performance.  This version does a bit of math to go right-left-right-left from center:

```
public static List<String> get_sinificativ_term(List<Dico> dicolist) {
    int size = dicolist.size();

    return IntStream.range(0, size)
            .map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? (size + i) / 2 : (size - i - 1) / 2)
            .mapToObj(i -> dicolist.get(i).getTerm())
            .distinct()
            .limit(1000)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: firstly thank you for help.
you forget this `collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Might be less intuitive to read, but `.map(i -> size+(i^i<<31>>31)>>1)` is a potentially more efficient alternative to `.map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? (size + i) / 2 : (size - i - 1) / 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like this?

```
public static List <String> get_sinificativ_term(List<Dico> dico) {
    List<String> list = dico.stream()
                            .map(Dico::getTerm)
                            .distinct()
                            .limit(1000)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(list.size() != 1000) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Need at least 1000 distinct values");
    }
    return list;
}
```

You need to check the size because you can have less than 1000 distinct values. If efficiency is a concern you can try to run the pipeline in parallel and measure if its faster.

Comment: I need 1000 distinct values from centre of distribution "median",because terms in Arraylist are sorted by weigth [median-500,median+500] are in the centre of statstical ditirbution of term in document